# Neo4j HA Cluster Error connecting to graph database using Bolt

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, amazon-elb, neo4j-ogm

We are using neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4 in cluster on AWS with bolt protocol. HAproxy is used to we know who is master and who are the slaves in the HA cluster. The Java application is using the spring-data-neo4j framework and is deployed on a Tomcat 7.

Structure on AWS is: Neo4j HA Cluster (1 master and 2 slaves) ---> HAproxy ----> ELB

We are receiving this error. An error does not occur every time but occasionally 
(yesterday 3 times).

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Error connecting to graph database using Bolt: N/A, Unable to close socket connection properly.Broken pipe
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newSession(BoltDriver.java:97) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(BoltDriver.java:71) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest(BoltRequest.java:153) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.execute(BoltRequest.java:139) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:93) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:73) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:313) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.query(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.query(Neo4jTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.query(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.bookings.SnapCardBookingService.getBookingsInternal(SnapCardBookingService.java:216) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.bookings.SnapCardBookingService.getBookings(SnapCardBookingService.java:249) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.bookings.SnapCardBookingService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d05944f4.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649) ~[spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.bookings.SnapCardBookingService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bfd16c77.getBookings(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.controller.BookingController.getBookings(BookingController.java:264) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at com.kubid.booking.service.config.RequestBodyFilter.doFilter(RequestBodyFilter.java:36) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to close socket connection properly.Broken pipe
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.stop(SocketClient.java:157) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.close(SocketConnection.java:181) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.close(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:163) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.PooledConnection.dispose(PooledConnection.java:180) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.onDispose(InternalConnectionPool.java:196) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.onDispose(InternalConnectionPool.java:178) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.dispose(ThreadCachingPool.java:197) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquireFromGlobal(ThreadCachingPool.java:145) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquire(ThreadCachingPool.java:118) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:107) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newSession(BoltDriver.java:95) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.close(TLSSocketChannel.java:452) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.stop(SocketClient.java:145) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.close(SocketConnection.java:181) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.close(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:163) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.PooledConnection.dispose(PooledConnection.java:180) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.onDispose(InternalConnectionPool.java:196) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.onDispose(InternalConnectionPool.java:178) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.dispose(ThreadCachingPool.java:197) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquireFromGlobal(ThreadCachingPool.java:145) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquire(ThreadCachingPool.java:118) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:107) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0-RC1.jar:1.0.0-RC1-cc9a365a0ad5346cb6ba50f3b68a998b4d956b98]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newSession(BoltDriver.java:95) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-2.0.1.jar:?]
```

This is our HAproxy .cfg:

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local0
   log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   maxconn 256
defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option dontlognull
    timeout connect 30s
    timeout client 2h
    timeout server 2h
frontend http-in
    bind *:81
    acl write_method method POST DELETE PUT
    acl write_hdr hdr_val(X-Write) eq 1
    acl write_payload payload(0,0) -m reg -i CREATE|MERGE|SET|DELETE|REMOVE
    acl tx_cypher_endpoint path_beg /db/data/transaction
    http-request set-var(txn.tx_cypher_endpoint) bool(true) if tx_cypher_endpoint
    use_backend neo4j-master if write_hdr
    use_backend neo4j-master if tx_cypher_endpoint write_payload
    use_backend neo4j-all if tx_cypher_endpoint
    use_backend neo4j-master if write_method
    default_backend neo4j-all
frontend http-browse
    bind *:83
    mode http
    default_backend neo4j-browser
backend neo4j-all
    option httpchk GET /db/manage/server/ha/available HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ [code]
    acl tx_cypher_endpoint var(txn.tx_cypher_endpoint),bool
    stick-table type integer size 1k expire 70s  
    stick match path,word(4,/) if tx_cypher_endpoint
    stick store-response hdr(Location),word(6,/) if tx_cypher_endpoint
    server neo4j-1 192.0.0.250:7687 check port 7474
    server neo4j-2 192.0.0.251:7687 check port 7474
    server neo4j-3 192.0.0.252:7687 check port 7474
backend neo4j-master
    option httpchk GET /db/manage/server/ha/master HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ [code]
    server neo4j-1 192.0.0.250:7687 check port 7474
    server neo4j-2 192.0.0.251:7687 check port 7474
    server neo4j-3 192.0.0.252:7687 check port 7474
backend neo4j-browser
    mode http
    option prefer-last-server
    option httpchk GET /db/manage/server/ha/master HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthorization:\ Basic\ [code]
    server neo4j-1 192.0.0.250:7474 check
    server neo4j-2 192.0.0.251:7474 check
    server neo4j-3 192.0.0.252::7474 check
listen admin
    bind *:82
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth admin:admin
```

We can not figure out where is a problem. Is it problem in:

1) `org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver`

2) ELB on AWS

3) HAproxy `.cfg`

4) Bolt protocol on AWS

Before we were using Bolt as protocol, we used the HTTP endpoint, with the same settings on AWS and we did not had problem.

### **EDIT**

We change configuration so this is what we know about our questions:

1) `org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver` - error is only appear here on Tomcat 7.

2) ELB on AWS - we not using ELB any more we are connecting directly to HAproxy

3) HAproxy .cfg - our PHP team using port 83 to connect to Neo4j HA Cluster using http protocol and they do not have errors.

4) Bolt protocol on AWS - we add logs on ELB and EC2 and we did not receive any error about Bolt protocol.

Is there a problem with neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4 and neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver 2.0.4?

### **EDIT**

There is a issue between neo4j-enterprise-3.0.4 or neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver 2.0.4 and AWS ELB or both.

We change our app settings and we are using Http driver with same structure on AWS instead of Bolt driver. We did not receive error.

We did not find a way to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you allow non-local connections using the Bolt protocol? What is the respective line in the `neo4j.conf`?

Comment: Yes we allowed non-local connections. Without that we will get error always not occasionally.  # Bolt connector
`dbms.connector.bolt.type=BOLT
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
# To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687`

# HTTP Connector
`dbms.connector.http.type=HTTP
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.encryption=NONE
# To have HTTP accept non-local connections, uncomment this line
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474`